# Deploying flex application to tomcat without eclipse plugin

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, blazeds

I am using flex sdk to develope my application, now i want to deploy it into tomcat server with blazeDS how to do it with out the eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this useful link in adobe site

http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=lcoverview_4.html